# "Concatenating" andFilter and orFilter for RowFilter

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter

I have a JTable with four columns, the first one containing either a number or a text, the other three only text. I'm trying to filter this table with the help of a RowFilter:

```
sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(myOwnTableModel);
```

The checkboxFilter I got works well enough:

```
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("^[0-9]$", 0));
```

This sorter is activated or deactivate depending on a checkbox that is either set or not.
The second filtering happens if a user puts some text in a textfield. For itself, this works fine already:

```
String regex = "(?i)" + Pattern.quote(s); // s = input Text of user
sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter(regex, 1,2,3));
```

What I can't do, is to activate both filters at the same time. Maybe I'm thinking way too far, my idea has been to "concatenate" the two filters, the checkboxFilter should be "and" the other "or". I tried several things, to me the most promising looked something like:

```
String regex = "(?i)" + Pattern.quote(s);
bookFilter = RowFilter.regexFilter(regex, 1,2,3);
sorter.setRowFilter(bookFilter.andFilter(Arrays.asList(
                    RowFilter.regexFilter("^[0-9]$", 0))));
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't lead to any usable result. Any ideas appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to add an `ActionListener` to the `JCheckBox` to update the filter state if the checkbox is toggled and to add a `DocumentListener` to the `JTextField`'s underlying Document to update the filter state if the contents of the field is updated.

The other bug in your code is that you are calling the static `andFilter` method on your `bookFilter` instance and are only passing in the newly constructed regex filter (i.e. **you are only passing in one parameter to `andFilter`**).  The correct usage is:

```
RowFilter andFilter = RowFilter.andFilter(filter1, filter2, etc);
```

**Example Event Listeners**

```
JCheckBox cb = ...
cb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    updateFilters();
  }
});

JTextField tf = ...
tf.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
  public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { updateFilters(); }
  public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { updateFilters(); }
  publci void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) { updateFilters(); }
});
```

... and then define your updateFilters() method to install a new filter based on when the checkbox is selected and whether the text field is empty or not.

**Example Filter Update Method**

```
public void updateFilters() {
  if (cb.isSelected()) {
    if (tf.getText().length() > 0) {
       // Both filters active so construct an and filter.
       sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(bookFilter, checkBoxFilter));
    } else {
       // Checkbox selected but text field empty.
       sorter.setRowFilter(checkBoxFilter);
    }
  } else if (tf.getText().length() > 0) {
    // Checkbox deselected but text field non-empty.
    sorter.setRowFilter(bookFilter);
  } else {
    // Neither filter "active" so remove filter from sorter.
    sorter.setRowFilter(null); // Will cause table to re-filter.
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I did two small changes:

    tf.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    updateFilters();
   }
  });
and I had to use the following construct to be able to add the two filters: 
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.andFilter(Arrays.asList(bookFilter, checkBoxFilter)));

though I don't exactly know why, but like this it works :)